# How to know if the iPhone is connected to the 4G+ (LTE-Advanced)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, network-programming, iphone-privateapi

To see if an iPhone is connected to 4G, I check the network using the following code :

```
import CoreTelephony

let telephonyInfo = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
telephonyInfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology
```

That return a String with the value of the const CTRadioAccessTechnologyLTE. But the CoreTelephony API don't have any const for LTE Advanced. So anyone know how to check if we're one a 4G+ network on iOS 9 ?